# Firehose to S3 Vs Direct PUT to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a requirement to PUT about 20 records per second to an S3 bucket.

That comes to roughly `20 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 51,840,000` PUTs per month.

I do not need any transformations but I would certainly want the PUTs to be GZIPped and partitioned by year/date/month/hour.

Option 1 - Just do PUTObjects on S3

1. Price comes to about ~$260 a month
2. I would have to do the GZIP/Partitions etc on the client side

Option 2 - Introduce a Firehose and wire it to S3

1. And let's say I buffer only once in 10 minutes then that is about `6 * 24 * 30 = 4,320` PUTs. Price of S3 comes down to $21. With each record about 20 KB Firehose pricing is about 1000GB * 0.029 comes to about $30. So total pricing is $51. Costs for data transfer / storage etc are same in both approaches I believe.
2. Firehose provides GZip/Partitions/buffering for me OOTB

It appears like Option 2 is the best for my use case. Am I missing something here?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you can buffer for 10 minutes in Firehose, why you can't buffer, lets say, for 1 hour on the client side when uploading to S3?

Comment: 10 minutes of lag time is acceptable. But to your point about why not buffer in the client app for 10 minutes, great point, but don't want to burden that app which is not built to scale. Would rather lean on AWS especially if I can get the job done without breaking the bank?